# Dual-Write creates similar records in Dataverse

Tags: integration, axapta, dataverse, dynamics-365-operations, power-platform

I set up Dual-Write between D365 F&O VendorsV2 and Dataverse table. However, sometimes I face the problem, when the vendor is created in D365 F&O, but in Dataverse Dual-Write creates multiple records with the same vendor, and the newer record contains more information than the older one (e.g the newest record contains the data about adress or telephone while the oldest one contains only the vendor name and number). How can I fix this issue? I set up duplicate detection rules, but it does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by myself. I added a key for the table in Dataverse and selected the pair of columns which combination should be unique. I also added these columns in the "Integration keys" settings for Dual-Write in D365 F&O.